# jquery Plugin using namespace instead of $.fn.extend

Tags: jquery

Hey I am looking to change my a plugin that I created to use the document namespace. I have been researching this but I am lost on how to do it.

Here is the start of the plugin code:

```
(function ($) {
        $.fn.extend({
                BGP: function (options) {
```

Currently the call to the plugin uses:

```
$(document).BGP({ /*options*/});
```

I want it to be more like:

```
$.BGP({ /*options*/});
```

Any help and explanation would be GREAT!

Comment: what precisely do you mean by `.BGP({});` ? The period is not valid as the first character

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean you want it to be a jQuery global function and pollute THAT namespace :), you probably want

```
$.BGP = function(options) {...
```

It's ok to do that in code (someone will say differently, no doubt, and they probably know better than I do) that you're only using on your own site, where you know that no one else will use that namespace, but a bad idea if you're planning to distribute the code (i.e. in a plugin).

Answer (score 0):

You're wanting to pollute the global namespace? ;) If so, just:

```
function BGP(options) { ...
```

Will do that. But the intent of a function like that is much different, because it's not acting on a certain target element like the jQuery plugin version does.